# Plotting in Elliptical coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-transformation

I want to plot an equation in elliptical coordinates. In the traditional elliptical system, Ellipse and hyperbola shares the same confocal point. Is there a plot function that draws a function in this system?  I do not want to parameterized in regular Cartesian. This will defeat the purpose.  For example. For example, having ***nu*** as the elliptical coordinate and ***Theta*** as the Hyperbolic coordinate, how I plot the hyperbolic function

***nu***=3(***Theta***)-2

**UPDATE (March 8, 2020):**

I must add that my above statement "defeat the purpose" is a wrong use of wording and  shows my misunderstanding in how Mathematica plot functions. There is no native elliptical coordinate system nor ellipsoidal coordinate functions. For those interested in transformation of elliptical system, please follow my post in the subject.
[SphericalPlot3D of an OblateSpheroid via coordinate transformation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149401/sphericalplot3d-of-an-oblatespheroid-via-coordinate-transformation)

Comment: What does it mean _" This will defeat the purpose"_? What is the "purpose"?

Comment: Defeat the purpose of having a different coordinate system still linked to the cartesian coordinates.

Comment: The meaning of the term "elliptical coordinate system" is that it provides a parametrization of points in a Cartesian frame, where every point is the intersection of an ellipse and a hyperbola. So to plot *in this coordinate system* is synonymous to forming Cartesian plot in the end, and therefore it is not clear at all what you mean by not having elliptical coordinates linked to the Cartesian ones. The name "elliptical coordinates" itself comes from the elliptical shape of the coordinate lines when drawn in Cartesian coordinates!

Comment: Explicit equations to transform from Cartesian to elliptic coordinates are given below https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309803947_A_Note_on_Elliptic_Coordinates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may have "defeated the purpose":

```
f[u_, v_, c_] := c {Cos[u], Sin[u]} {Cosh[v], Sinh[v]}
Show[ParametricPlot[{f[u, 3 u - 2, 1], f[u, 3 u - 2, -1]}, {u, 0, 
   2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.01]]],
 ParametricPlot[{f[u, v, 1], f[u, v, -1]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 5}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #4 &}, 
  Mesh -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.3], Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.3]}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Purple, Orange}, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {LightBlue, LightBlue}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'm confused by the "defeat the purpose" statement, but here's a shot.  I'm well out of my league here, and tossing this answer out since I was interested in learning something about coordinate transformations in Mathematica.

```
tr = CoordinateTransformData["Elliptic" -> "Cartesian", 
   "Mapping", {nu, theta}] /. nu -> 3 theta - 2
ParametricPlot[% /. \[FormalA] -> 1, {theta, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

I'm unsure how to handle the Formal A.